High school inequality: how to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \prod_{r = 1} ^ n \frac{3 ^ r}{3 ^ r - 1}\right) < 2?$
I'm having trouble with proving the inequality
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \prod_{r = 1} ^ n \frac{3 ^ r}{3 ^ r - 1}\right) < 2.$$
Using Desmos, a graphing calculator, I found that the limit's value is around $1.785$ for $n = 1000$. However, I don't really have any idea how to continue.
Could anyone offer some hints or ideas?
(I'm not sure whether there is a closed form for the stated limit, and it would be better if someone could validate whether a closed form exists or not.)

See art of problem solving, and replace $2$ by $3$.

@DietrichBurde Thanks!

Based on the suggestion by Dietrich Burde, you can first prove with convexity or by studying the difference that for $x \in [0, 1/3]$, $-\ln(1-x) \leq \frac43 x$ then
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{r=1}^\infty \frac{3^r}{3^r - 1}
&= \exp\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{3^r}{3^r - 1}\right)\right)
= \exp\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty -\ln(1-3^{-r})\right) \\
&\leq \exp\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{3^r}\right) 
= \exp\left(\frac{4}{3} \frac{1/3}{1-1/3}\right) = e^{2/3} = 1.9477... < 2 \\
\end{align}$$
I don't think we can find an exact solution because of the following formulas
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^\infty -\ln(1-3^{-r})
&= \sum_{r=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{rk} k} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{rk}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \frac{(1/3)^k}{1-(1/3)^k} \\
\end{align}$$
Which is the first formula. The second follows from applying Lambert series
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \frac{(1/3)^k}{1-(1/3)^k}
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{3^m} \sum_{d | m} \frac{1}{d} 
= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{3^m} \sum_{d | m} \frac{\frac md}{d \frac md} \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{m 3^m} \sum_{d | m} \frac md
= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{m 3^m} \sum_{d | m} d \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma(m)}{m 3^m} \\
\end{align}$$
where we have used the sum of divisors function.
to sum up
$$
\prod_{r=1}^\infty \frac{3^r}{3^r - 1} = \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{3^k-1}\right) = \exp\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma(m)}{m 3^m}\right) < 2.
$$

Wow, the use of Lambert series is totally unexpected for me. Thanks for your detailed response!

Induction looks like a good idea. The problem here is that the right side of the inequality is constant.
You can try proving a stronger result:
$$\left( \prod_{r = 1} ^ n \frac{3 ^ r}{3 ^ r - 1}\right) < 2-\frac{1}{3^n} \forall n>0.$$
And now you proceed by induction.

Thank you for your reply! Yes, I just verified in details that the method is indeed correct, and it is very succinct.
